# Is it possible use KVO with generic types in swift4

Tags: swift, generics, key-value-observing, swift4

My method receive a generic type in parameters which associated with protocol. Inside this method I use additional `NSObject` class to wrap/hide generic type because `KVO` only works with `ObjC` classes.
An example is given below:

```
protocol OutputData: NSObjectProtocol {
    associatedtype Output
    var dataContainer: DataContainer<Output>? { get set }
}

class DataContainer<O>: NSObject  {
    var outputData: O?
}

func injectResult<O: OutputData>(from: O) {
    let dataCont = from.dataContainer
    observer = dataCont?.observe(\.outputData) { (object, change) in
        let data = object.outputData as! Data
        self.inputData  = data
    }
}
```

In this situation I don't see any compile time errors but if I try to run this code I get the next exception:

```
Could not extract a String from KeyPath
Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Concurrency.DataContainer<Foundation.Data>, 
                                        Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>>: 
file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift, 
line 85
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might not solve the problem, but you need to declare `outputData` as `dynamic @objc` in order to use KVO with it.

Comment: Yep, didn't solve the problem. I've declared objcMembers class and dynamic objc inside that class where I use them.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid it wouldn't help. The problem here is probably that KVO is an Objective-C Cocoa feature, and Objective-C cannot deal with Swift generics.